# Splitting a single index list into multiple list indexes?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
lst = ['words in a list']
```

and I was hoping to split each one of these words in the string into their own separate indexes. So for example, it would look something like this:

```
lst = ['words','in','a','list']
```

I'm wondering if this is possible? I thought initially this would be just a simple lst.split() with a loop, but it seems like this is will throw an error.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
print(lst[0].split())
```

If the list has more elements:

```
print([x for i in lst for x in i.split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Split only works for a string type. So you need to index the list item first and then split.

lst = lst[0].split()

Comment: How is this not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this when you have a list of string or single string inside a list

```
 lst = ['this is string1', 'this is string2', 'this is string3']
 result =' '.join(lst).split()
 print(result)
 # output : ['this', 'is', 'string1', 'this', 'is', 'string2', 'this', 'is', 'string3']
```